# How to organize <li> into columns?

Tags: html, css

I have a undefined list with 6 items. I want to organize these items in 2 columns, odd in left, even in right side, regardless the item content height.

CSS basically:

```
ul li
{
    list-style:none;
    width:270px;
    background:#eee;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd)
{
    float:left;
}

ul li:nth-child(even)
{
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
```

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/cbacelar/x9jLdg8k/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `display: inline-block` without `float`. Just make your LI width: 50%.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/x9jLdg8k/2/

Changed your `ul li` rules to the following: Added `width:50%` as well.

```
ul li
{
    list-style:none;
    width:50%;
    background:#eee;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Good! If you look with attention, item '4' is away from item 2. How to climb all items, to the above item base?

Comment: I think a table element would be much more suitable than a list if that's what you want.

Comment: I can't use table... Is it impossible with UL?

Comment: Just a PITA if you're trying to match heights. May need to be done through javascript, or not use a UL and use Divs. Does it absolutely have to be a UL?